# cargo-maven3-plugin stopped running

Tags: deployment, tomcat9, cargo

I had a working project, but suddenly it stopped running

I'm launching the TomCat 9.0.60 via cargo plugin version 1.10.1.
After "mvn clean package cargo:run" an exception occurs when restarting:

"org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to create a Tomcat 9.x standalone configuration: Invalid configuration dir [/target/cargo/configurations/tomcat9x]. When using standalone configurations, the configuration dir must point to an empty directory - Except if the configuration was created by Cargo."

I not understand  what happends.
Why it occurred and what needs to be done to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In our project, we used another plugin (sass-maven-plugin) to create a file in the target/load/configuration/tomcat9x
As a result
, sass-maven-plugin created a file inside "target/cargo/configuration/tomcat9x".  cargo-maven3-plugin thought that the "target/cargo/configuration/tomcat9x" directory was already configured by him and did not add the necessary files. Appeared "org.codehouse.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to create a Tomcat 9.x standalone configuration".

variants to fix:

1. create a file in ".cargo" in "target/cargo/configuration/tomcat9x"
2. do not create files in target/cargo/configuration before the container starts.  After the container starts, you can create files